# Differential Equation, Implicitly Defined Solution

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was given the differential equation

$$\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{2t+1}{2u-2}, u(0)=-1$$

My Attempt:

$$du(2u-2)=dt(2t+1)$$
$$\int2u \text{ d}u - \int2 \text{ d}u = \int2t \text{ d}t + \int\text{d}t$$
$$u^2-2u+C_1=t^2+t+C_2$$
$$C = C_2-C_1$$
$$u^2-2u=t^2+t+C$$

I couldn't figure out how to solve for $u$ in terms of $t$ and solve the initial condition given. Obviously this is implicitly defined, so how would I go about finishing the problem?

Comment: Your formula is a quadratic in $u$ - you could re-arrange and use the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To finish the problem, use the initial condition: $u(0)=-1$. This means that $u=-1$ for $t=0$. This will give you $C=3$ and $u^2-2u=t^2+t+3$. Now observe that $t^2+t+3>0$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$. The equation $u^2-2u=p$ where $p>0$ has solutions $u_1=1+\sqrt{1+p}$ and $u_2=1-\sqrt{1+p}$. The first is always positive and second always negative. Our initial condition tells us we want the negative, so
$u=1-\sqrt{1+p}$ and finally plug in $p=t^2+t+3$.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to see how to approach this once you write in the variables for your implicit solution:

$$u(t)^2  - 2u(t) = t^2 + t + C$$

If $u(0)=-1$, let $t=0$, and whenever $u(0)$ appears let that be $-1$, and then solve for $C$:

$$u(0)^2 - 2u(0) = 0^2 + 0 + C \implies (-1)^2 - 2(-1) = C \implies C=3$$